# Nomenklatura and keys

Tags: java, properties, internationalization

I have no idea where to ask elsewhere than here.

We got a whitelable-solution and different mandants in different languages, ok. The problem is how to name the keys.

In example:

```
loginname1=nickname
loginname2=Nickname
loginnames1=nicknames
loginnames2=Nicknames
loginnames3=nickname's
loginnames4=Nickname's
login.error.invalid=Your $loginname1 has not been found. \\
  $loginname2 must contain at least two numbers. $loginnames4 firstchar \\
  must be upcase. ...
```

Ok, this is designt to easyly switch from the name "Nickname" to "Loginname". Now we use this in differnet languages. In German loginname1 may be "Benutzernamen" xor "Benutzername" pending of the person in the sentence. This may get realy wired now.

Actually i need to change a key for login, "Einloggen" instead of "Anmelden" like:

```
login_imperativ_3person_singular=Anmelde
```

This construct create a wild orgy of about 20 wordings.

Any rule that i need in other languages like chineese (_common, _demure)?

Comment: I don't think you can continue with this approach! It is too complicated. I would get rid of "loginname1", etc. and JUST have "login.error.invalid=" with all the text in the one string.

The problem is that you are trying to extract words to avoid repeating them ("nicknames"). But, you are causing more problems by doing that. In other languages, you cannot just pull a word out and substitute it. Have a look at Welsh language :)  You need the entire sentence in one piece for it to make sense.

Comment: I concur with @MrSpoon, keep to entire sentences. Work with variants, **de** German, **de_CH** Swissly German, maybe **cn_CN_DEMURE**. That is easier on the translators, though for me I would have liked your analytic approach.

Comment: This just won't work when you need to use things like [Inflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection), [Grammatical mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood) or [Gender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender). And you'd have to do that in many languages. Why in the world you came up with this solution? What are your goals?

Comment: My Goal is to change only one key instead of tenthousand.